# Website which shows CocoaPods libraries sorted by github stars

Tags: ios, github, cocoapods

I am looking for good iOS Libraries and Frameworks.

I discovered the great CocoaPods library manager and its great!

But its really hard to find the really goods libraries in CocoaPods. The search functionality is not very advanced. But most of the libraries are on github.

Now I am wondering if someone has already done a sorting of the CocoaPods libraries according to the github stars? So that I can find the very good or widely used libraries easy on CocoaPods.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you have a specific need and you look for it, for example: go to GitHub and put "iOS Charts". A bunch of libraries will pop-up, pick the one you like. Then, check if it is on CocoaPods. If it's not, just drop an email to the guy who created the Library to add it there.